# Convert BIGINT to TIMESTAMP in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

While converting BIGINT to TIMESTAMP, junk value is coming. See the query below.
Appreciate any help.

```
scala> spark.sql("select cast(cast(cast(CAST('2015-11-15 18:15:06.51' AS TIMESTAMP) as double)*1000 + cast('64082' as double) as bigint) as timestamp) " ).show(truncate=false)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CAST(CAST(((CAST(CAST(2015-11-15 18:15:06.51 AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE) * CAST(1000 AS DOUBLE)) + CAST(64082 AS DOUBLE)) AS BIGINT) AS TIMESTAMP)|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|47843-07-20 09:36:32.0                                                                                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why is the result a "junk value"? What result do you expect? And, more importantly, what have you done to demonstrate (via very simple code examples) that the expected result is, in fact, a reasonable expectation?

Answer (score 1):

Using Spark 1.6

- Typecasting a TIMESTAMP to DOUBLE will convert to seconds since
  1970-01-01.
- Typecasting a BIGINT to TIMESTAMP will convert from
  seconds since 1970-01-01.

Your example seems to imply you think casting BIGINT to TIMESTAMP converts from milliseconds since 1970-01-01 which doesn't seem to be the case. And so you end up with a junk value.

Note that according to this ticket the behavior is actually configurable: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3454

Answer (score 0):

casting bigint to timestamp receives epoch time in seconds.
Try without multiplying by 1000:

```
select cast(cast(cast(CAST('2015-11-15 18:15:06.51' AS TIMESTAMP) as double) + cast('64082' as double) as bigint) as timestamp)
```

Though this would loose millis precision.